# android system webview update not taken into account

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android tablet running lollipop (5.0.2).
I updated the android system webview to the latest version using google play. But I am under the impression that the apps are still using the old system webview.

How can I check which version of the webview is used by my apps?

I got an app to alert navigator.userAgent, and I get:

> Version/4.0 Chrome/39.0.0.0

Is this the answer?

EDIT: If so, then how can I get the apps to use the new android system webview I just installed?

Comment: What leads you to believe that is not the right answer?

Comment: I don't quite understand how to read the userAgent response, I find it confusing.